# Apache Kylin - "Timeout visiting cube" and other weirdness

Tags: hadoop, olap, mapr, kylin, bigdata

I've installed Kylin with MapR distribution, and things seem to work
fine up to a point.  I ran the sample.sh script and I now have the
"learning_kylin" project, and I can run "build" on the cube and the
job reports success at 100% complete.

But.. after doing this, the display always shows my cube as being 0.0
bytes, and if I run the sample query from the documentation, I get a
"timeout visiting cube" error.

The other weird thing I've noticed, is that the "build" dialog is
showing a start date of today's date, and I can't edit it.  Not sure
if that has anything to do with the weirdness I'm seeing or not, but
can anyone tell me how Kylin determines what value to put there?

Anyway, any thoughts on how to debug this are greatly appreciated.
I've examined the logs, but don't see anything that jumps out to me as
terribly useful.  Here's what I find:

```
==========================[QUERY]===============================
SQL: select part_dt, sum(price) as total_selled, count(distinct
seller_id) as sellers from kylin_sales group by part_dt order by
part_dt
User: ADMIN
Success: false
Duration: 0.0
Project: learn_kylin
Realization Names: [kylin_sales_cube]
Cuboid Ids: [64]
Total scan count: 0
Result row count: 0
Accept Partial: true
Is Partial Result: false
Hit Exception Cache: false
Storage cache used: false
Message: Error while executing SQL "select part_dt, sum(price) as
total_selled, count(distinct seller_id) as sellers from kylin_sales
group by part_dt order by part_dt
LIMIT 50000": Timeout visiting cube!
==========================[QUERY]===============================

2016-04-30 03:45:32,310 ERROR [http-bio-7070-exec-9]
controller.BasicController:44 :
org.apache.kylin.rest.exception.InternalErrorException: Error while
executing SQL "select part_dt, sum(price) as total_selled,
count(distinct seller_id) as sellers from
kylin_sales group by part_dt order by part_dt LIMIT 50000": Timeout
visiting cube!
       at org.apache.kylin.rest.controller.QueryController.doQueryWithCache(QueryController.java:224)
       at org.apache.kylin.rest.controller.QueryController.query(QueryController.java:94)
       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
       at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:213)
       at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:126)
       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:96)
       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:617)
       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:578)
       at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:789)
```

Edit: Looking at HBase with hbase shell, I can see that Kylin is definitely connecting to HBase, at least enough to create tables and what-not. But the table that appears to be the backing store for the cube, is empty.

```
hbase(main):006:0> list
TABLE                                                                                                                                                                   
KYLIN_PC2ZBJAZEC                                                                                                                                                        
kylin_metadata                                                                                                                                                          
2 row(s) in 0.0270 seconds

=> ["KYLIN_PC2ZBJAZEC", "kylin_metadata"]
hbase(main):007:0> list 'KYLIN_PC2ZBJAZEC'
TABLE                                                                                                                                                                   
KYLIN_PC2ZBJAZEC                                                                                                                                                        
1 row(s) in 0.0160 seconds

=> ["KYLIN_PC2ZBJAZEC"]
hbase(main):008:0>
```

Answer (score 0):

please post in kylin's dev mail list for help: dev@kylin.apache.org
here's an archive for your issue: http://apache-kylin.74782.x6.nabble.com/Timeout-visiting-cube-td4618.html